# Array shows single characters instead of full items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wasn't sure how else to word the title. I've been trying to figure this out for a few hours out now and it's driving me crazy. For my first project, I'm trying to make a little browser-based text game. The problem is with how inventory items are being added to my inventory list. Instead of

- One
- Two
- Three

I'm getting

- O
- n
- e
- T
- w
- o

And so on.

It still adds the item but just not as one whole list entry. The list displays just fine with the default item the character has, just not after you've picked something up.

Here's my code -

JS Script #1:

```
//change rooms
if (rooms[currentRoom].items !== undefined) {
Object.values(rooms[currentRoom].items).forEach(function(value) {
  $('#game-text').append("<p>" + value + "</p>");
});
} else {
$('#game-text').append("<p>You find nothing.</p>");
   }
}

//pick up items
function pickUp(item){
if (rooms[currentRoom].items[item] !== undefined) {
    inventory = inventory + item;
    $('#game-text').append("<p>A " + item + " has been added to your inventory.</p>");
} else {
    $('#game-text').append("<p>That is not a valid item.</p>");
}
}

//displays player commands
function showHelp() {
$('#game-text').append("<p>Here are the possible commands: </p>");
$('#game-text').append("<p><ul>");
for (var i = 0; i < commands.length; i++) {
    $('#game-text').append("<li>" + commands[i] + "</li>");
}
$('#game-text').append("</ul></p>");
}
//displays player inventory
function showInventory() {
if (inventory.length === 0) {
    $('#game-text').append("<p>You are not carrying anything!</p>");
    //return;
} else {
$('#game-text').append("<p>Here is your inventory: </p>");
$('#game-text').append("<p><ul>");
for (var i = 0; i < inventory.length; i++) {
    $('#game-text').append("<li>" + inventory[i] + "</li>");
}
$('#game-text').append("</ul></p>");
}
}

//converts player input to actions
function playerInput(input) {
var command = input.split(" ")[0];
switch (command) {
    case "go":
        var dir = input.split(" ")[1];
        changeRoom(dir);
        break;
    case "help":
        showHelp();
        break;
    case "inventory":
        showInventory();
        break;
    case "examine":
        examineRoom();
        break;
    case "pickup":
        var item = input.split(" ")[1];
        pickUp(item);
        break;
    default:
        $('#game-text').append("<p>Invalid command!</p>");
}
}

//Manipulates DOM (screen)
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#game-text').append("<p>" + rooms.start.description + "</p>");

$(document).keypress(function(key) {
    if (key.which === 13 && $('#user-input').is(':focus')) {
        var value = $('#user-input').val().toLowerCase();
        $('#user-input').val("");
        playerInput(value);

    }
})
})
```

In the previous script, I'm fairly certain the problem lies in either the pickUp 
function, showInventory function, or "pickup" case. It's drawing from this 
script-

JS Script#2:

```
var rooms = {
"start": {
    "description": "You are in a dark, cold place and you see a light to 
<b>north</b>\
 and you hear the sound of running water to the <b>west</b>",
    "directions": {
        "north": "clearing1",
        "west": "bridge1"
    },
    "items": {
        "dagger": "You spot a rusty old dagger. Better than nothing I 
suppose.",
    },
},
"clearing1": {
    "description": "You arrive to a clearing, you see a lighthouse to the 
<b>north</b>\
 and there is a strange smell coming from the <b>east</b>",
    "directions": {
        "south": "start",
        "north": "lighthouse",
        "east": "trolls"
    },
    "items": {
        "shield": "You spot a worn leather shield."
    },
},
"lighthouse": {
    "description": "You arrive to the lighthouse and walk up to the door. A 
strange old lady\
 opens the door. What do you do?",
    "directions": {
        "south": "clearing1"
    }
},
"trolls": {
    "description": "You arrive to another clearing, there are some trolls 
roasting some mysterious meat\
 They haven't seen you yet. What do you do?",
    "directions": {
        "west": "clearing1"
    }
},
"bridge1": {
    "description": "You see a river and there is a bridge to the 
<b>west</b>",
    "directions": {
        "east": "start",
        "west": "bridge2"
    }
},
"bridge2": {
    "description": "You try to cross the bridge but a troll jumps out and 
bites your leg!",
    "directions": {
        "east": "bridge1"
    }
}
}
```

Any help or guidance would be seriously appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is `inventory` defined? What is it's initial value? Does it have one?
Depending on what it's initial value is, what do you think this does `inventory = inventory + item`? Based on your code and expected output, you are expecting `inventory` to be an array. Did you mean to do something like `inventory.push(item)`?

Answer (score 2):

Your inventory is a `string` you treat it like an array.

Use `push` and declare your inventory as an array (it's a global)

```
inventory.push(item);
```

A string has the `length` property, it tells us how many characters are in a string. You can iterate over them. That causes the unwanted behaviour in your code:

```js
console.log("--String--");
    var inventory = "Hello world";
    for (var i = 0; i < inventory.length; i++)
    {
        console.log(inventory[i]);
    }
    
    //as opposed to:
    console.log("--Array--");
    
    var inventory = ["String one", "String two", "String three"];
    inventory.push("String four"); //use push to expand array
    for (var i = 0; i < inventory.length; i++)
    {
        console.log(inventory[i]);
    }
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad to be of service. Really dive into MDN documentation: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript), it's gonna really help you understand the concept of the language.